# 'return' from try block in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++11

I have a very simple question on C# and C++: is it a good practice to use `return` in try block? A long time ago I heard that it can produce some troubles for a compiler. But probably the modern compilers can handle this situation.
Sample code:

```
try
{
   //do something
   return 25;
   //do something else
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: C++ and C# are *very* different languages, please don't conflate them. For example, it's not good practice in C# to manage pointers; while it is in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return at anytime, it's not bad practice to have a return statement in the try block and even the catch block. Actually, it often improves readability